# Is "Everyone is welcome along." a valid sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Is "Everyone is welcome along." a valid English sentence?

My English grammaticality is basic at best and I'm not sure how to even research this...

EDIT: I'm adding a bounty, and I'd like to know why, if "Everyone is welcome along," is ungrammatical, the similar phrase "Everyone is welcome aboard" is grammatical. Both *along* and *aboard* can be adverbs, so why can't both be used as an adverb here.  (Or are both grammatical, but one is just unidiomatic?)

Comment: You do not need to say 'grammaticality'. It is used by people who think they get extra points for long words. All you need say is 'My English grammar is basic...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to say no, but I can't back that up with a *"why,"* aside from the fact that I've never heard it before.

However, *"you're welcome **to come** along"* definitely *is* acceptable and commonly used. It is used when, say, someone's going to the store to buy something. They may say to their friend, *"you're welcome to come along,"* if they desire (or wouldn't mind) their friend's company to the store.

**(EDIT: That said, I don't think that *"everyone is welcome along"* would be totally unheard of. The context I would expect that to be in similar context to *"everyone is welcome to come along,"* above.)**

Comment: @jejorda2 shouldn't the comma be after the quotation marks

Comment: @AkashVartak In AmE, the comma goes [inside the quotation mark](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48447/placement-of-comma-before-quotation-mark) whether or not it is part of the quoted text.

Comment: @jejorda2 there is no "right" or "wrong" way in placing punctuation marks in quotations, just different styles— [*it was a pleasant surprise to find Ben Yagoda of Slate praising the "logical punctuation" that we are said to use in the UK. Specifically, he notes a "punctuation paradigm shift" away from the traditional US practice of placing commas and full points (periods) inside quotation marks.*](http://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2011/may/19/mind-your-language-punctuation-quotations)

Answer (score 6):

There is absolutely nothing ungrammatical about "welcome along" whatsoever.

The performative adjective "welcome" standardly takes locative preposition phrases as Complements. The preposition phrase indicates the location of the speaker or that which the addressee is headed towards. Sometimes the prepositions take noun phrase Complements, sometimes they take  preposition phrases as Complements and sometimes they take no Complement at all—in other words they are intransitive. Here are some examples with preposition phrases containing noun phrase Complements:

- Welcome to our humble abode!
- Welcome aboard the Boeing 787 Dreamliner!
- Welcome onto the Team Joe!

Some examples with prepositions taking preposition phrase Complements:

- Welcome back from the spring break!
- Welcome down to paradise rock.
- Welcome through to the other side.

Some examples with intransitive uses of prepositions:

- Welcome back!
- Welcome aboard!
- Welcome through!
- Welcome ashore!
- Welcome down!
- Welcome home!
- Welcome along!

*Welcome along* is particularly used when somebody is being welcomed to an activity or journey for the first time. We find, therefore examples such as this one from [the University of Edinburgh](https://iad4phd.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/welcome-alongback-2/) with the title "Welcome along /back" where they greet new students and welcome back returning ones.

As "welcome" is a performative (by saying the word you perform the action it describes), it is far more common in spoken English and on signs and brochures than in formal written texts. There's not much point in looking up such phrases on Google books therefore.

*Welcome along* is certainly not formal in tone. However, that is completely irrelevant to whether it is grammatical or not. It is, of course, perfectly grammatical. How do we know? Because native speakers of English use it!

---

<sup>Thanks to Mari-Lou A for *Welcome home*</sup>

Comment: But the OP's sentence is *Everyone is welcome along*, in "Welcome along!" isn't that more of an exclamation rather than a full sentence? *Welcome back* is idiomatic but what about [*Everyone is welcome back*](https://www.google.it/search?q=Everyone+is+welcome+back&oq=Everyone+is+welcome+back&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22Everyone+is+welcome+back%22&tbm=bks)?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sure, it's just easier to illustrate with a short adjective phrase, but it doesn't matter if the adjective is a PC: "Hey everyone, we're having a barbecue at ours tomorrow afternoon, everyone is welcome along. Just turn up and, of course, bring something to stick on the barbie".  Similarly "Thank you once again for believing, and though we hope we don't have to see you again, our door is always open to you and you're always welcome back." Similarly ...

Comment: @Mari-LouA  You're going to get more results with you than everyone because, as I mentioned the adjective welcome is most often used performatively. So you need a situation where the addressee is everyone! But that's perfectly possible.

Comment: You're repeating yourself now :). I'm fine with "*Welcome back / aboard / home*" and at a stretch "Welcome along" but "You are welcome along" doesn't cut the mustard with me, unless it's "You're welcome to tag/come along" or "You're welcome to join us"

Comment: @Mari-LouA [Loads of examples from newspapers here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everone+is+welcome+along%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=H48wV6KDJs7U8gemw7ToCg#q=%22everyone+is+welcome+along%22+newspaper&start=10)

Comment: There's over 120K hits for [*welcome to tag along*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22welcome+to+tag+along%22&start=240&filter=0)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ah, but that's without the *everybody is*! You get 204K for ["welcome along"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everone+is+welcome+along%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=H48wV6KDJs7U8gemw7ToCg#q=%22welcome+along%22) :) You get  8 hits for ["everybody is welcome to tag along"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everone+is+welcome+along%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=H48wV6KDJs7U8gemw7ToCg#q=%22everybody+is+welcome+to+tag+along%22) ...

Comment: @Mari-LouA  and 490 for ["everybody is welcome to come along"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everone+is+welcome+along%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=H48wV6KDJs7U8gemw7ToCg#q=%22everybody+is+welcome+to+come+along%22&start=475&filter=0) . The upshot seems to be that they're both ok, would you say?

Comment: All of the examples listed above are completely different than the one that is: welcome along. Welcome through is also wrong.

Comment: @Lambie [Maybe have a browse through the 200,000 examples here?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22everone+is+welcome+along%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=H48wV6KDJs7U8gemw7ToCg#q=%22welcome+along%22)

Comment: The consensus of the answers is that it's grammatical, and nobody gave any good reasons that it's ungrammatical. This answer is slightly more comprehensive than the others, so it gets the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is welcome aboard [the ship, vessel, plane, etc. or metaphor thereof].

/The captain welcomed guests aboard [the ship]/.

In that sentence, **aboard is a preposition** in the implied phrase. It is not a single adverb as it would be in: to ships came close aboard. It's an adverbial phrase.

/Everyone is welcome **to** come along [with me, them, etc.]/ is grammatical. Leaving out the to is non-standard and may be regional. I have never heard it before reading it here. For me, to /come along/ is either a semi-phrasal verb or a prepositional phrase.

/They are welcome to come along [with you]/: semi-phrasal verb in an implied preposition phrase.

/They came along later in the day [to the school]/: a semi-phrasal verb, often seen in BrE, to mean come to a place. Similar to pop around and show up (AmE). Same as previous sentence.

come along is the semi-phrasal verb for the non-phrasal verb accompany: /He came along to the school with me/ = He accompanied me to the school.

For me, a semi-phrasal means the verb actually implies a prepositional phrase that has been dropped over time.

For example: to stand up meaning to stand on one's feet in a vertical position is not a semi-phrasal verb versus to come along [with me] is.

The implied prepositional phrases are adverbial.

Comment: *"Everyone is welcome to come along " ... Leaving out the to is non-standard and may be regional.* <--- Do you mean leaving out "to come". Just that nobody's suggesting  "Welcome come along" is well-formed!

Comment: Are you misreading me on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

A usage summary, using online tools.  Books: **no**.  Newspapers: mainly **no**.  Web: *yes*.  Therefore it's more of a casual usage, not *formal*.  Details...

*Google Ngram* for ["Everyone is welcome along"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22everyone+is+welcome+along%22&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&search_plus_one=form&direct_url=) searches a great many scanned books, but returns **0** hits.

A search of *Google's* current newspaper database turns up one [*near* hit](https://www.google.com/#q=%22everyone%20is%20welcome%20along%22%20site:news.google.com/newspapers&gws_rd=ssl):

> Everyone in the congregation is welcome along with anyone in the
> community who likes fellowship and fun.

But note the *implied* comma after "welcome", i.e.:

```
Everyone ... is welcome, along with anyone ... who likes ...
```

(Since there's no dangling "along", that's not a match.)

Plenty of hits out there on [the web](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22everyone+is+welcome+along%22&search_plus_one=form) however:

> Everyone is welcome along to the special event.
>
> Everyone is welcome along in support.
>
> everyone is welcome along for the ride.
>
> Everyone is welcome along to learn
>
> Everyone is welcome along!

Comment: You haven't said if it's grammatical or not :0 [Maybe "welcome along" is not used in books very much because books don't normally welcome people?]

Comment: Other answers already addressed its grammar, and I'd nothing new to add.  _Google Ngram_ has many hits for "[everybody is welcome](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everyone+is+welcome&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&search_plus_one=form&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ceveryone%20is%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BEveryone%20is%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Beveryone%20is%20welcome%3B%2Cc0)".

Answer (score 1):

It is valid.  And used.  Perhaps if you Google "welcome along" you will be convinced of this...

> Please take a look at the upcoming fundraising Events & Sponsorship - everyone is welcome along to events and if you would like to take part or get involved get in touch.

.

> Reception Class Assembly
>   Our Reception Class will be performing their assembly this Wednesday afternoon and all Parents and Carers are welcome along to watch.

And many more.

Comment: In written form it borders on illiteracy....shame on that school.

Comment: I disagree that "not common here" means "borders on illiteracy".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is valid.  I did a quick search and found "Everyone is welcome along" in newsletter/event announcement contexts, however none of them appeared to be American. The usage may not be regional to the United States, but from what I found in "social media" genre usage (casual register) that included audiences in Australia, New Zealand, Scotland, and a few sites with the ".uk" suffix, it is valid.

I think U.S. English users are more accustomed to the "to come" inserted before the "along" OR they want the "along" to be followed by another phrase like "for the ride", or "to the fair".  My guess is, as you have written it above, it feels incomplete to American ears and tongues, but I believe it is an issue of regionality, or of being regionally dialectic, or dialectically regional...or should I should I just say "regional" or "dialect"...?  (And no, I'm not talking about Hegel's hood.  Please forgive me my linguistic dilletantishness - or is it dillettantism - and my *qua* linguistic cant.)

Nonetheless, I don't think it has to do with a naturally occurring gap, in which case if it does, it would still be grammatical, or not ungrammatical; that is to say a naturally occurring gap, though not of standardized (or standard) usage, could indicate this is an emerging form that has yet to be analyzed and formally codified.

But, if its formality and codification you want, enjoy the following:

-- From my old and fabulous 1971 Webster's Seventh New Collegiate Dictionary:

**along** *adv*
   3: as a companion or associate

```
  < brought his wife ~ >
```

So, with this usage (or is it use?) the substitution works:

**Everyone is welcome along.
 = Everyone is welcome _____ (as a companion or associate).**

p.s.  I do like the way you chose grammaticality in your question, and that you tagged it as such. I've always understood that term to describe one's own meta-awareness and level of facility with a grammar;  referring to one's own fluency as a user of grammar. I didn't realize that this forum defines it as referring to an utterance and its conformity to grammar. Your question, to me, is asking three things; you're wanting to check your own grammaticality, and the grammaticality of the sentence, while you're also asking for proof. Perhaps next time, tag for both grammaticality and grammar, lest your nonconformity to tagging etiquette irk the ire of those who would accuse you of opportunistic pendanticality.   = )

- "A speaker's linguistic competence, which is the knowledge that they have of their language, allows them to easily judge whether a sentence is grammatical or ungrammatical based on intuitive introspection. For this reason, such judgements are sometimes called introspective grammaticality judgements."  (Grammaticality - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia)

Comment: I think the word introspection is misused in that description.

Comment: @Lambie - Do you mean that it in the way it is paired with intuitive?

Comment: If so, I found this article that makes a clear distinction:  "Intuition, introspection and observation in linguistic inquiry"  Abstract: "...explores the relationship between intuition, introspection and the observation of naturally occurring utterances in linguistic inquiry...Its aim is to clarify...the role of introspective judgments and the status of linguistic intuition...to establish the intersubjective, language-specific semantic values of cases on the basis of intuition, as distinguished from introspection."
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0388000112000575

Comment: This would make a really cool discussion topic...now how to pose the question...?

Comment: Bonnet yes, for me introspection occurs over time and has all sorts of implications. When I look at a sentence or phrase or utterance, it does not take much time for me to decide whether something is, for example, idiomatic.

Answer (score -2):

In the context the word "along" is unnecessary, meaningless and irritating. Unfortunately, however, that does not make it ungrammatical.

It is used increasingly by radio and television presenters. When I am sitting at home listening or watching, I appreciate being welcomed – but I have no intention of going "along" anywhere.

Comment: There is no context. You made up a context of sitting at home. In the context of a walk through the park, everyone is welcome along.

Comment: Everyone is welcome TO come along.