# Should the comma in this sentence fall before the quotation in the word "We"? Thank you

Tags: punctuation

Never give up on someone with a mental illness. When "I" is replaced by "We", Illness becomes Wellness.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please see the question already answered at *[Placement of comma before quotation mark](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48447/)*

Comment: That's a clever saying.